# How to launch Activity from Broadcast SMS Receiver?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I have created a Broadcast receiver which successfully displays`Toast` message whenever user receives a message..Now I want to display an Alert Box for the same activity.

I have written the following code based on that help but its not Opening the `AlertActivity` on success condition. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
  public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

        final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

            //Some More code 

            if(senderNum.equals("345")){
                    Intent alertActivity = new Intent(context, AlertActivity.class);
                    alertActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(alertActivity);
             }
             else{
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,   "Error " , duration);
                    toast.show();
              }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Cant see where senderNum is set, have you tried logging to make sure its what you expect, no country prefixes etc. / Have you tried starting the activity for any condition just to check if the intent works? Also, please post the manifest, thanks

Comment: @Kirmani88 can we have the log output?